# How much of CSS3 can be accessed via javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Have been pondering on this question for a while and just because I don't want to spend a lot of time doing trial-and-errors:

How much of css3 properties can I access via the good 'ol javascript?

or in other words:

can I fool around with -webkit-, -moz- ,etc properties of an element? And as well, can I add the same to an element?

Please note that creating a style ,then appending it and finally setting the element's attribute to the class is not going to cut it for what I have in mind :\

Comment: As much as a browser supports.

Comment: Hm, you can't access `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Comment: put on hold? Never asked for any code.. just a one line answer :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much everything can be set at a node level. The weakness is in working with the actual css.  You can certainly set the -webkit or -moz properties.  Just drop the "-" and use camel case when referring to the properties.  Note that the same transform is not applied to values (see below). So -webkit-transition-property becomes webkitTransitionProperty.  Adding these to an element is done through the style property.  So

```
node.style.webkitTransitionProperty = "-webkit-transform";
```

Comment: Won't work, you don't need to add `Property` to the property name.

Comment: Odd, works fine in my apps.  Seriously, I was trying to show a three word term so just chose to set the property of the transition, not the aggregated set as webkitTransition would do.  Code stands.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to check if support exists .

For prefixes of different browsers, you can use [Prefixr](http://prefixr.com/).

If you use SASS, look at [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I would say if CSS3 can do it javascript can do it aswell but this might depend on the browser. But you can assume that almost every style attribute can be manipulated by javascript. Note that the names can be different like `-mox-boxshadow` and in javascript `element.style.mozBoxShadow`